# joomla3.2 - blank error when saving item with tags - self-developed component

Tags: tags, joomla3.2, joomla-component

I am developing a joomla3.2 component.

In order to use tags, I have added the `JTableObserverTags` to my `JTable`, like so:

```
class FoodAndDeliveryTableItem extends JTable
{
    public function __construct(&$db)
    {
        parent::__construct('#__foodanddelivery', 'id', $db);
        JTableObserverTags::createObserver($this, array('typeAlias' => 'com_foodanddelivery.item'));
    }
```

I have also inserted the content type to `#__content_types` table:

```
INSERT INTO `website_content_types` 
(`type_id`, `type_title`, `type_alias`, `table`, `rules`, `field_mappings`, `router`, `content_history_options`) VALUES
(null, 'FoodAndDelivery Item', 'com_foodanddelivery.item', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__foodanddelivery","key":"id","type":"Item","prefix":"FoodAndDeliveryTable"}}', '', '', 'FoodAndDeliveryHelperRoute::getItemRoute', '{"formFile":"administrator\\/components\\/com_foodanddelivery\\/models\\/forms\\/item.xml"}')
```

That should be enough, should it?
Instead, I get this error:
[image: blank error]

---

i was trying to solve it on my own. for `com_content` for instance, i understand that `JTableObserverTags` is added to `JTable` in `libraries/cms.php`. I did this in my table declaration, and the observer works fine, it's methods are fired correctly.

Inside `JTableObserverTags` though, when `onBeforeStore` even is fired, it is searching for `$this->table->tagsHelper->tags`:

```
public function onBeforeStore($updateNulls, $tableKey)
{
    $this->parseTypeAlias();
    if (empty($this->table->tagsHelper->tags))
    {
        $this->tagsHelper->preStoreProcess($this->table);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->tagsHelper->preStoreProcess($this->table, (array) $this->table->tagsHelper->tags);
    }
}
```

But I don't understand why. When `save` method of `JModelAdmin` is fired, it is storing it  to `$table->newTags` like so:

```
if ((!empty($data['tags']) && $data['tags'][0] != ''))
{
    $table->newTags = $data['tags'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The problem is that I only half-read tutorials.

---

In [Using Tags in an Extension](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aUsing_Tags_in_an_Extension) tutorial, in `Create a content type for each view` section, they write:

> If your table does not contain a field, put “null” instead. Leaving it blank may cause SQL issues. The special fields are optional. At a minimum for common fields you need to map: content_item_id, alias and title in order to successfully create urls in the tagged items list.

I left `field_mappings` blank, and this it what caused the error.
The row I should have inserted into `#__content_types` is:

```
INSERT INTO `website_content_types` 
(`type_id`, `type_title`, `type_alias`, `table`, `rules`, `field_mappings`, `router`, `content_history_options`) VALUES
(null, 'FoodAndDelivery Item', 'com_foodanddelivery.item', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__foodanddelivery","key":"id","type":"Item","prefix":"FoodAndDeliveryTable"}}', '', '{"common":{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"state","core_alias":"alias","core_body":"description","core_publish_up":"publish_up","core_publish_down":"publish_down","core_featured":"featured","core_catid":"catid"}}', 'FoodAndDeliveryHelperRoute::getItemRoute', '{"formFile":"administrator\\/components\\/com_foodanddelivery\\/models\\/forms\\/item.xml"}');
```